# unrecognized selector sent to instance [UIImage] swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am new to Swift language and I want to implement a swipe gesture to my image so that I can change the page with it. For example when you received a whatsapp notification on any iPhone home screen. But when I am adding swipe gesture programmatically it gives me this error.

```
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: swipeImage, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))

rightSwipe.direction = .Right

view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

the error is when I am giving the id of my UIImage named swipeImage it gives me unrecognized selector sent to instance but when I give it named self it doesn't give me an error. But i want to add swipe gesture to my image. I hope I explained my problem.

Edit 1: Eventhough i changed the target to self.swipeImage it gives me the same error. Also I added addGestureRecognizer to my image by changing view to swipeImage but it does not work too

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `target` is the object wants to have the `action` called on it when the swipe happens.

It is not possible to add a gesture recognizer to a `UIImage`. They need to be added to `UIView` subclasses like `UIImageView`. You just need to use the `addGestureRecognizer:` method on the image view to add it.

```
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))

imageView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

Comment: I did it but it does not take the action at all. I put a label and changing it when the swipe method called and when I am trying to swipe right my label does not change. By the way thanks for giving an answer

Comment: I forgot to make it user interaction enabled. Thanks for the answer.